# Typing the Enter/Return key in Selenium

Tags: selenium, automation, automated-tests, keypress, enter

I'm looking for a quick way to type the <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd> key in Selenium.

Unfortunately, the form I'm trying to test (not my own code, so I can't modify) doesn't have a <kbd>Submit</kbd> button. When working with it manually, I just type <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd>. How can I do that with the Selenium `type` command as there is no button to click?

Comment: This might help http://asynchrony.blogspot.com/2008/11/enter-key-press-in-selenium.html

Comment: @croixhaug: What are you using? Selenium RC or WebDriver (Selenium 2)? What about language? Java? C#? or what?

Comment: @RiponAlWasim, in 2009 (when the question was asked) there were no WebDriver. Also the answers for both have been here for a while...

Comment: @AlexOkrushko: yes, you are right

Comment: This post is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413044).

Answer (score 359):

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys

WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

---

*The `import` statement is for Java. For other languages, it is maybe different. For example, in Python it is `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys`*

Comment: I believe that it's moved. `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503489/python-selenium-example-doesnt-work-says-no-module-named-keys)

Comment: @HJames Broadhead: I have checked it, the Keys class for the actual JAVA (2.17.0) is still `org.openqa.selenium.Keys`

Comment: WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN); this code is perfect for WebDriver (not for Selenium RC). More details example for google search: driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys("Ripon Al Wasim");
driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);

Comment: I know that return is different than enter, but how is Keys.ENTER different? (I would think that Keys.RETURN would simply make it more obvious that it is a bot doing the action?)

Comment: @NoBrainer: Quick look at imported file will answer your question:     `RETURN = '\ue006'` `ENTER = '\ue007'`. But why? Some relic or OS differences.

Comment: @NoBrainer: Enter and Return are different keys, have a look at the image of this wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enter_key

Comment: @Ralph Thanks for your solution. It's worthy for upvote.

Comment: for python:

`from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys` 
`password_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`

Answer (score 260):

### Java

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Value")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

OR,

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Value")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

---

### Python

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver.find_element_by_name("Value").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

OR,

```
driver.find_element_by_name("Value").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

OR,

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("Value")
element.send_keys("keysToSend")
element.submit()
```

---

### Ruby

```
element = @driver.find_element(:name, "value")
element.send_keys "keysToSend"
element.submit
```

OR,

```
element = @driver.find_element(:name, "value")
element.send_keys "keysToSend"
element.send_keys:return
```

OR,

```
@driver.action.send_keys(:enter).perform
@driver.action.send_keys(:return).perform
```

---

### C#

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("Value")).SendKeys(Keys.Return);
```

OR,

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("Value")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

Comment: For Python, I found that appending "\n" to the input string is the most straightforward way to go. It worked in a search field.

Answer (score 44):

You can use either of  ***`Keys.ENTER`*** or ***`Keys.RETURN`***. Here are the details:

### Usage:

- *Java*:

  - Using *`Keys.ENTER`*:

    ```
    import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
    driver.findElement(By.id("element_id")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    ```
  - Using *`Keys.RETURN`*:

    ```
    import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
    driver.findElement(By.id("element_id")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
    ```
- Python:

  - Using *`Keys.ENTER`*:

    ```
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    driver.find_element_by_id("element_id").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    ```
  - Using *`Keys.RETURN`*:

    ```
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    driver.find_element_by_id("element_id").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    ```

*`Keys.ENTER`* and *`Keys.RETURN`* both are from `org.openqa.selenium.Keys`, which extends `java.lang.Enum<Keys>` and implements `java.lang.CharSequence`.

---

### Enum Keys

**Enum Keys** is the representations of pressable keys that aren't text. These are stored in the Unicode PUA ([Private Use Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas)) code points, 0xE000-0xF8FF.

### Key Codes:

The special **`keys codes`** for them are as follows:

- **RETURN** = **`u'\ue006'`**
- **ENTER** = **`u'\ue007'`**

The implementation of all the **`Enum Keys`** are handled the same way.

Hence these is **No** **`Functional`** or **`Operational`** difference while working with either **`sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);`** or **`WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);`** through **Selenium**.

---

### Enter Key and Return Key

On computer keyboards, the <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or the <kbd>Return</kbd> on Mac OS X) in most cases causes a command line, window form, or dialog box to operate its default function. This is typically to finish an "entry" and begin the desired process and is usually an alternative to pressing an <kbd>OK</kbd> button.

The <kbd>Return</kbd> is often also referred as the <kbd>Enter</kbd> and they usually perform identical functions; however in some particular applications (mainly page layout) <kbd>Return</kbd> operates specifically like the **Carriage Return** key from which it originates. In contrast, the <kbd>Enter</kbd> is commonly labelled with its name in plain text on generic PC keyboards.

---

### References

- [Enter Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enter_key)
- [Carriage Return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return)

Answer (score 29):

Now that Selenium 2 has been released, it's a bit easier to send an Enter key, since you can do it with the `send_keys` method of the `selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement` class (this example code is in Python, but the same method exists in Java):

```py
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> wd = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> wd.get("http://localhost/example/page")
>>> textbox = wd.find_element_by_css_selector("input")
>>> textbox.send_keys("Hello World\n")
```

Comment: Or more generally, values from `Keys` (import can be `selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys`), `Keys.RETURN` in this case.

Answer (score 16):

In Python

**Step 1.** `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys`

**Step 2.** `driver.find_element_by_name("").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`

**Note:** you have to write `Keys.ENTER`

Answer (score 12):

When writing HTML tests, the ENTER key is available as `${KEY_ENTER}`.

You can use it with `sendKeys`, here is an example:

```
sendKeys | id=search | ${KEY_ENTER}
```

Comment: What 'language'/context? [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) (command line)? Linux? Can you add some context to your answer?

Comment: It's for HTML tests suites

Answer (score 9):

```
selenium.keyPress("css=input.tagit-input.ui-autocomplete-input", "13");
```

Answer (score 9):

You just do this:

```
final private WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.id("myId"));
input.clear();
input.sendKeys(value); // The value we want to set to input
input.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

Comment: just out of curiosity , why do you prefer writing 3 lines of code which you can write in a single line

Comment: Isn't an "import" of sorts needed for `Keys`? In Python, it would be "`from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys`".

Answer (score 7):

For those folks who are using WebDriverJS `Keys.RETURN` would be referenced as

```
webdriver.Key.RETURN
```

A more complete example as a reference might be helpful too:

```
var pressEnterToSend = function () {
    var deferred = webdriver.promise.defer();
    webdriver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('id-of-input-element')).then(function (element) {
        element.sendKeys(webdriver.Key.RETURN);
        deferred.resolve();
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Answer (score 6):

For [Selenium Remote Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)#Selenium_Remote_Control) with Java:

```
selenium.keyPress("elementID", "\13");
```

For Selenium WebDriver (a.k.a. Selenium 2) with Java:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("elementID")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Or,

```
driver.findElement(By.id("elementID")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

Another way to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in WebDriver is by using the *Actions* class:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.id("elementID")), Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 6):

`driver.findElement(By.id("Value")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);` or `driver.findElement(By.id("Value")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);`

Answer (score 6):

```
search = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@type='text']")
search.send_keys(u'\ue007')
```

#ENTER = u'\ue007'

Refer to Selenium's documentation 'Special Keys'.

Comment: This answer work but accidently voted it down because I used the wrong number.

Comment: Can you link to the documentation?

Answer (score 5):

I just like to note that I needed this for my Cucumber tests and found out that if you like to simulate pressing the enter/return key, you need to send the `:return` value and *not* the `:enter` value (see the values described [here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/0.2.0/Selenium/WebDriver/Keys))

Comment: This is also true for a GWT input text field.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use an XPath expression for searching the element and then, the following code works:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='txtFilterContentUnit']")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Comment: If the element has ID, it is better to use ID instead of xpath

Comment: What language? Isn't an "import" of sorts needed for `Keys`? In Python, it would be "`from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys`".

Answer (score 4):

You can call `submit()` on the element object in which you entered your text.

Alternatively, you can specifically send the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to it as shown in this Python snippet:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER) # 'element' is the WebElement object corresponding to the input field on the page
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for "how to press the Enter key from the keyboard in Selenium WebDriver (Java)",then below code will definitely help you.

```
// Assign a keyboard object
Keyboard keyboard = ((HasInputDevices) driver).getKeyboard();

// Enter a key
keyboard.pressKey(Keys.ENTER);
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 3):

To enter keys using Selenium, first you need to import the following library:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys
```

then add this code where you want to enter the key

```
WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

You can replace RETURN with any key from the list according to your requirement.

Comment: What list? Can you link to it?

Comment: What language? Python?

Answer (score 3):

There are the following ways of pressing keys - C#:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.Id("Value")).SendKeys(Keys.Return);
```

OR

```
OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions action = new OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions(Driver);
action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Escape);
```

OR

```
IWebElement body = GlobalDriver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));
body.SendKeys(Keys.Escape);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
object.sendKeys("your message", Keys.ENTER);
```

It works.

Answer (score 3):

When you don't want to search any locator, you can use the *Robot* class. For example,

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: Can you link to documentation for the `Robot` class?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to press the Enter key (python):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

Comment: this answer works perfectly `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//xpath').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`
in case for search works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

It could be achieved using Action interface as well. In case of WebDriver -

```
WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
username.sendKeys(searchKey);
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
action.perform();
```

Comment: Isn't an "import" of sorts needed for `Keys`? In Python, it would be "`from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys`".

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
selenium.keyPress("id="", "\\13");
```

Answer (score 2):

For Ruby:

```
driver.find_element(:id, "XYZ").send_keys:return
```

Answer (score 2):

For Selenium WebDriver using [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) (if the key is visible):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of text field")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

or,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of text field")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to send the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in the middle of a text. So I passed the following text to send keys function to achieve `1\n2\n3`:

```
1\N{U+E007}2\N{U+E007}3
```

Comment: Re *"keys function"*: Do you mean `send_keys()` (this is about Python)?

Answer (score 2):

If you are in this specific situation:

a) want to *just* press the key, but you not have a specific webElement to click on

b) you are using Selenium 2 (WebDriver)

Then the solution is:

```
    Actions builder = new Actions(webDriverInstance);
    builder.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).perform();
```

Comment: Is "webElement" literal?

Answer (score 2):

**Java/JavaScript:**

You could probably do it this way also, **non-natively**:

```
public void triggerButtonOnEnterKeyInTextField(String textFieldId, String clickableButId)
{
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
        "   elementId = arguments[0];
            buttonId = arguments[1];
            document.getElementById(elementId)
                .addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                        document.getElementById(buttonId).click();
                    }
                });",

        textFieldId,
        clickableButId);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

Comment: What language? [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29)?

Answer (score 1):

For everyone using **JavaScript / Node.js**, this worked for me:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath('xpath')).sendKeys('ENTER');
```