# python selenium example doesn't work, says no module named Keys

Tags: python, selenium

I installed selenium via pip on a windows machine.

Just tryout out the sample on the website:

```
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox
browser.get("http://www.yahoo.com") # Load page
assert browser.title == "Yahoo!"
elem = browser.find_element_by_name("p") # Find the query box
elem.send_keys("selenium" + Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(0.2) # Let the page load, will be added to the API
try:
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'http://seleniumhq.org')]")
except NoSuchElementException:
    assert 0, "can't find seleniumhq"
browser.close()
```

I changed from time to import time and the error it was giving for that went away, now I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "test.py", line 3, in module
from selenium.common.keys import Keys
ImportError: no module named Keys
```

Is the sample out of date?

Answer (score 13):

From http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1491  :

> from selenium.webdriver.common.keys
>   import Keys

Answer (score 0):

It seems your selenium installation is not in path, find out Selenium installation folder inside python installation. something like
C:\Python33\selenv\Lib\site-packages

or run it using command selenv\Scripts\python.exe yourseleniumscript.py from python installation folder.

Answer (score -2):

copy C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\keys.py
to C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\common

Comment: The problem is versioning of selenium. Your suggestion would allow an import (maybe), but will break anything which imports keys.py using its new parent module.