# Press TAB and then ENTER key in Selenium WebDriver with Ruby

Tags: ruby, tabs, selenium-webdriver, keypress, enter

I am doing automated testing using Selenium WebDriver with Ruby. I need to click a button. I cannot get the button element by id or css or xpath as the button is transparent. I would like to use Tab and Enter key to press the button.

I can use Tab key to get the button as below:

```
@element.send_keys :tab
@element --> any javascript element visible in the browser
```

But how do I use the Enter key on the button?

Basically I need to achieve press Tab key and then press Enter key to click the button.

I am using Selenium WebDriver `@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox`

Answer (score 7):

In Ruby user1316's code looks like

```
driver.action.send_keys(elementVisible, :tab).send_keys(elementVisible, :return).perform
```

Answer (score 3):

Keeping in mind the excerpt :

> I can use tab key to get the button as
>
> @element.send_keys :tab
>
> @element --> any javascript element visible in
>   the browser
>
> but how do i use the enter key on the button??

In order to use the enter key on the button, you could try one of the solution provided using Ruby [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6661301/948641). This  basically talks about sending the `:return` value and not the `:enter` value i.e  `@element.send_keys :return` and some additional information.

**UPDATED:**

I could provide some code in Java which tries to implement the problem conceptually using the info provided [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions#Getting_started_%28short_how-to%29). You could try to translate for the corresponding Ruby Selenium API.

The Code:

> Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
>
> builder.sendKeys( elementVisible, Keys.TAB).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
>
> Action submitTheTransperentButton = builder.build();
>
> submitTheTransperentButton.perform();

Comment: it doesnot help.  My case is that i cannot get the button element. But i still need to click the button. Is there any other better way to achieve this? thank you

Answer (score 1):

use `Selenium::WebDriver::Keys::KEYS[:tab]`

ref: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/Selenium/WebDriver/Keys

Answer (score 0):

send ENTER in ruby:

```
@browser.action.send_keys("\n").perform
```

Comment: I think this doesn't work for me, like if I try going to google and typing asdf, then doing ENTER manually it works. Whereas if I use irb and programmatically start google and programmatically enter in asdf or manually type asdf. Then programmatically send ENTER, it doesn't work, whereas a manual enter does