# Press Enter Key in Selenium RC with C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-rc, keypress, enter

How to press Enter using Selenium RC using C#?

I am working with a `SearchBox` using `Selenium`. 
In which I have to type some name and I have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to search.

There is no `Submit` button. So, I must use <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I tried something like this

```
selenium.KeyPress("quicksearchtextcriteria", "13");
```

But doesn't work.

Please Help.

Note: I made a collection of possible ways to do this. See here: [press enter key in selenium](http://coding-issues.blogspot.com/2012/11/press-enter-key-in-selenium.html)

Comment: just a side note, why aren't you using selenium 2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be achieved by [`Keys`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Keys.htm), and [`Enter`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/F_OpenQA_Selenium_Keys_Enter.htm).

Example in Java as I don't know C#:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;

//...

// this sends an Enter to the element
selenium.type("locator", Keys.ENTER);

// or even this - this sends the "Any text" and then confirms it with Enter
selenium.type("locator", "Any text" + Keys.ENTER);
```

From the [`Keys`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html) enum.

Comment: import org.openqa.selenium.Keys; itself giving error. i am working with Visual studio. c#

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. That was Java, I didn't recognize C# from the snippet. Isn't there an alternative in C#? Maybe not, I don't know.

Comment: The link for c# alternative isn't working. Is there a c# alternative to this - {code} selenium.type("locator", "Any text" + Keys.ENTER); {code}

Comment: The error message for the bad links is: The requested URL /svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Keys.htm was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

Comment: I fixed the links. Note that this answer is 6 years old now, and Selenium RC is looong gone. Go for WebDriver!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

> import org.openqa.selenium.Keys
>
> WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN)

**References:**

**[Typing Enter/Return key in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629053/typing-enter-return-key-in-selenium)**

**http://asynchrony.blogspot.com/2008/11/enter-key-press-in-selenium.html**

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I try this, I get the following error in Visual Studio 2017: "Argument 1 cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.Keys' to 'string' - the API SendKeys requires a string.

Answer (score 3):

This is how it done with C#:

webElement.SendKeys(Keys.Return);

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can also use the 'Submit' method. (Though I use Selenium 2, so I'm guessing perhaps this is not possible in Selenium RC? Sorry if so).

```
//First you need to find the searchBox and fill it, once doing so call
searchBox.Submit();
```

Comment: Or: searchBox.SendKeys("Text to search" + OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
selenium.KeyPressNative("13");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one

```
selenium.keyDown("locator of element", "\\13");
```

Comment: Here what is mean by locator of element?  is dat mean xpath of my textBox ?

Comment: Yes, just put xpath of text-box

Comment: Hmm. I tried.But not working. No error. But Enter is not working

Comment: When i debug it, it is saying Expression was evaluated but has no Value.

Comment: quicksearchtextcriteria is ID of field???If yes then try to use locator as ID=quicksearchtextcriteria...I think that was xpath error message

Answer (score 0):

You can use clickAt("locator",""); If keyPress is not working. It will work for sure.