# Selenium script fails to work in Jenkins

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a selenium script that works fine locally, as well as when run on the command line of the build machine.  But when I run through Jenkins, I am getting different results.  (this is a continuation of an [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799875/press-enter-key-in-selenium-script/10799927#10799927) - asking as a new question because I *think* it's a different issue)

My intention is to enter the field data, press Enter, press Tab to leave field/fire the javascript - this will cause a new field (formOrBundleType) to appear.

```
    selenium.keyPress("program", "\10");
    selenium.type("program", "MIC HOMEOWNERS");
    selenium.keyPress("program", "\10");

    // slight hack - tabbing out of this field forces the form
    // to repaint, exposing the formOrBundleType field
    selenium.keyPressNative(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_TAB + "");

    // now grab the exposed field and start the data entry again
    selenium.keyPress("formOrBundleType", "\10");
    selenium.type("formOrBundleType", "HO3 ENHANCED");
```

In Jenkins, I am getting:

```
[junit] 13:59:48.761 INFO - Command request: type[program, MIC HOMEOWNERS] on session 44eb
[junit] 13:59:54.761 INFO - Got result: OK on session 44eb
[junit] 13:59:54.776 INFO - Command request: keyPress[program, ] on session 44eb
[junit] 14:00:00.776 INFO - Got result: OK on session 44eb12edb47f4a14aa2f3c7733f2ff52
[junit] 14:00:06.776 INFO - Command request: keyDownNative[9, ] on session 44eb
[junit] 14:00:06.776 INFO - Creating Robot
[junit] 14:00:06.792 INFO - Got result: OK on session 44eb
[junit] 14:00:13.105 INFO - Command request: keyPress[formOrBundleType, ] on session 44eb
[junit] 14:00:19.105 INFO - Got result: ERROR: Element formOrBundleType not found on session 44eb
```

I've changed all kinds of timing settings, to see if the issue is with the return from the javascript call/painting the form.   Has anyone else run into this?

Comment: Can you add a line of code like selenium.isVisible(locator) before selenium.keypress and see what value its returning?

Comment: I found a workaround, by selecting the previous field:  selenium.keyPress("program", "\10");   --- this action causes the event to fire / expose the new field.  Not the best solution, but its effective.   Thank you for your feedback!