# Selenium Webdriver enter multiline text in form without submitting it

Tags: java, forms, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a multiline text and when I am simply putting the whole text into a form using sendKeys, the form gets submitted on each line break.

I tried replacing the newline with carriage return this way:

```
String myText="Some Multiline Text....";
myText=myText.replace("\n","\13");
```

This simply removed the newlines and I could not see the newline in output text.

Also below did not work(it also submits form at line breaks):

```
String myText="Some Multiline Text....";
myText=myText.replace("\n","\r");
```

So how do I go about with newlines in sendkeys without submitting the form?

Comment: The literal `"\13"` is in octal, and is `chr(11)` which is a vertical tab. A line feed is `"\n"` or `"\u000a"`, and a carriage return is `"\r"` is `"\u000d"`.

Comment: @hege_hegedus I tried that on basis of this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11540219/1291122

Comment: I think they might made a mistake. I can't find it in the documentation, but I think that should be `"\\13"`, so the string literal doesn't get escaped.

Comment: @hege_hegedus yeah it should be `"\\13"`. FYI I also tried with double slashes :p So I would suggest you to go ahead and edit that post to get some extra points ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is not a Selenium issue, pressing enter in a text field often submits the form. Usually you can bypass it by using Shift+Enter to insert a new line. Try this:

```
String myText = "first line\nsecond line";
myText = myText.replace("\n", Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT, Keys.ENTER));
myElement.sendKeys(myText);
```

Comment: Not working with python 3.5, 
#imported below class
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

But getting error "AttributeError: type object 'Keys' has no attribute 'chord'"

Comment: @Dr_Dang This is Java code, not python. The python bindings do not have `Keys.chord`, use an `ActionChain` instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915900/error-type-object-keys-has-no-attribute-chord

Comment: Is there any alternative for this in python3 ?

Comment: @Dr_Dang yes, by using `ActionChain`. Please ask a new SO question specific to python3, so we can answer it properly.

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me using python 3 was make use of ActionChain as Tamas said and @Arount posted on [Python and Selenium - Avoid submit form when send_keys() with newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45236253/python-and-selenium-avoid-submit-form-when-send-keys-with-newline)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://foo.bar')

inputtext = 'foo\nbar'
elem = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('div')
for part in inputtext.split('\n'):
    elem.send_keys(part)
    ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).key_down(Keys.ENTER).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).key_up(Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

Comment: this works, but for my multi line (say 100+) comment, the time taken to create the message is considerable. As it is an activity done in DOM. Can it be sped up? Like pasting just one time would be perfect

Comment: this is the only working solution I have seen so far. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following method for selenium. I added 2 samples. Msgbox and sendkeys

```
Dim myText As String = "hello\nYes"
myText = myText.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine)
MsgBox(myText)
exDriver.FindElement(By.TagName("input")).SendKeys(myText)
```

**Output**

[imgur output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei0vX.png)

Comment: question  was  about java  not vb.net