# Error: type object 'Keys' has no attribute 'chord'

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting below error while executing selenium code.

**Code:**

```
driver.find_element_by_id(PlaylistManagerLocators.Folder_Name).send_keys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"), "Auto_Folder5763")
```

**Error:**

> AttributeError: type object 'Keys' has no attribute 'chord'

I have imported all required files.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains


driver.find_element_by_id(PlaylistManagerLocators.Folder_Name).send_keys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"), "Auto_Folder5763")
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no function as `chord` in class [`selenium.webdriver.common.keys.Keys`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.common.keys.Keys) (Check the docs). You can simply split it into 2 statements.

```
driver.find_element_by_id(id).send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
driver.find_element_by_id(id).send_keys("Auto_Folder5763")
```

Or if you want to simultaneously have the keys pressed then you can try using [`selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains).

Comment: Yes it worked for me with below code:driver.find_element_by_id(PlaylistManagerLocators.Folder_Name).send_keys(Keys.CONTROL,'a')
            driver.find_element_by_id(PlaylistManagerLocators.Folder_Name).send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
            driver.find_element_by_id(PlaylistManagerLocators.Folder_Name).send_keys("Auto_Folder5764")                       
            driver.find_element_by_id(PlaylistManagerLocators.Folder_Name).send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an answer for a scenario some readers may encounter (I don't have enough reputation to add this as a comment), if the webform has control keys disabled and you want to replace prefilled text with your own string then this could work:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('elementID').value='new value'")
```

You can also try calling `.clear()` on the element or simulating a triple click in action chains but an autofill or autoreplace function my still be triggered on `.send_keys()` in which case directly setting the attribute with javascript may be the best/only option.