# Selenium Action Chains not letting me paste in Chrome

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium on Python. And I already have some data on my clipboard, but when I use action chains to paste the data:

```py
paste = ActionChains(driver)
paste.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+'v')
paste.perform()
```

It just types lowercase v. How do I make it still use action chains but have it paste?

Comment: Could you try a regular `send_keys` instead of using `ActionChains`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915900/error-type-object-keys-has-no-attribute-chord), I think you can just use a regular `send_keys` command to paste things, just as you are doing when you copy. I don't think there is a need for `ActionChains`.

`elementToPasteTextInto.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+"v")`

Alternatively, you can send text to the element using Javascript instead:

```
webdriver.executeScript("document.getElementById('elementID').setAttribute('value', 'new value for element')");
```

Comment: the thing is that I need action chains to paste into the page. if I dont specify action chains then I need to specify what element I want to paste into, but the element im trying to paste into always says non interactable. but if I just press ctrl v without clicking any where on the page, then it pastes what I want. so i just want some code that will let me paste into the page without having to specify the html element.

Comment: Perhaps that’s the reason `ActionChains` isn’t working correctly, because of the `ElementNotInteractable` state. Even if your code does not encounter the exception with AC, it could still be the problem.  You could try to send keys with JavaScript to the element instead of using `ActionChains`. I’ve updated my post with an example