# How to "send_keys" multiple lines in textarea in Python Selenium Appium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, appium-android

I need to fill the body of an email client application on a real smartphone.
I am using Python 3.7 + Appium.

I tried to send_keys a text with '\n' for each new line but it didn't work.

This is the string:

```
text="Bonjour {username},\nJe recherche des testeurs pour un nouveau logiciel marketing.\\nVoudriez-vous le tester?\nCordialement."
```

and when I do send_keys:

```
p_body.send_keys(text)
```

**it fill the textarea as a single line with the string \n inside the text. it doesn't lake 'new line'. :-(**

I could try with ActionChains, but it doesn't accept the special characters with accents.

Anyone already tried to fill a paragraph of multiple lines in an input with Appium and send_keys?

Comment: Did the `\\n` show up also or just the single backslash? On some systems you need `\r\n` (escaped would be `\\r\\n` to output a carriage return. See if those work.

Answer (score 2):

To fill the body of an email client application using send_keys including `\n` for each new line you can use the `execute_script()` method as follows:

```
p_body = driver.find_element_by_id('element_id')
text = "Bonjour {username},\nJe recherche des testeurs pour un nouveau logiciel marketing.\\nVoudriez-vous le tester?\nCordialement."
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].value=arguments[1]', p_body, text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi fellow french stackoverflow user ;)

According to Tamas Hegedus on this post : [Selenium Webdriver enter multiline text in form without submitting it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783394/selenium-webdriver-enter-multiline-text-in-form-without-submitting-it), you can try to replace the `/n` with `Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT, Keys.ENTER)`

Hope it helps

### EDIT

This solution doesn't work for Python, but for Java.
The right answer, as said in [Error: type object 'Keys' has no attribute 'chord'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915900/error-type-object-keys-has-no-attribute-chord), is using ActionChains

Comment: Thanks, but as you said : It doesn't work for Python. I need python solution if it exists.

Comment: I edited my answer with the link to the solution for Python.