# Python and Selenium - Avoid submit form when send_keys() with newline

Tags: python, selenium, sendkeys

I am using **Python 3** with selenium.

Let's assume `var = "whatever\nelse"`

My problem is that when I use `elem.send_keys(var)` it sends the form after *"whatever"* (because of the newline)

How may I replace "whatever\nelse" with whatever + **SHIFT+ENTER** + else?

Or is there any other way to input newlines without actually using javascript or substituting newlines with the newline keystroke?

**Note**: elem is a contenteditable div.

Comment: is it a textarea or input ? I checked with textarea and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @GaurangShah it is a contenteditable div in a form. Why so? Because of a WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: it could be something wrong with that div, probably check with your dev. I check on the w3chool and it works perfectly with `contenteditable p`. you can check that too. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_contenteditable

Comment: @GaurangShah Thank you. The problem is that the div is not mine. It belongs to the whatsapp web platform.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Did you tried something like:

```
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).key_down(Keys.ENTER).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).key_up(Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

Like

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://foo.bar')

inputtext = 'foo\nbar'
elem = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('div')
for part in inputtext.split('\n'):
    elem.send_keys(part)
    ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).key_down(Keys.ENTER).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).key_up(Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

`ActionChains` will chain `key_down` of SHIFT + ENTER + `key_up` after being pressed.

Like this you perform your `SHIFT` + `ENTER`, then release buttons so you didn't write all in capslock (because of SHIFT)

PS: this example add too many new lines (because of the simple loop on `inputtext.split('\n')`, but you got the idea.

Comment: Python says: AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'key_down'

Comment: hm, let me check

Comment: Thank you for your time. Your answer looks like the perfect approach so far.

Comment: yes, but I've messed it :p Was too confident about my selenium skills :) PS: fixed

Comment: It still will not create the new lines. I put a `chat.send_keys("NEW")` before every new line, just to make sure the action is being taken. But it prints everything in a line like. "text par 1. NEW. text part 2..." Also, if I do SHIFT + ENTER manually, it works fine. Meaning that `ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).key_down(Keys.ENTER)` is not working. But there is no traceback.

Comment: It works fine if you change the last both key strokes. As: `ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).key_down(Keys.ENTER).key_up(Keys.ENTER).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).perform()`

Comment: For me it worked as suggested by @ÁlvaroN.Franz, by releasing ENTER before SHIFT...

Comment: @ÁlvaroN.Franz I am trying to do this but I get a strange error, and my text is written multiple times almost randomly. Can you look at my question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66133462/selenium-with-python-newline-with-shiftenter-works-but-messes-up-the-text)

Comment: this works, but for my multi line (say 100+) comment, the time taken to create the message is considerable. As it is an activity done in DOM. Can it be sped up? Like pasting just one time would be perfect