# How can I get selenium to get a keyboard press of shift + enter at the same time using python?

Tags: python, selenium

I've made a whatsapp bot and a web scraper to get coronavirus cases and I want to send each data on a newline.  Eg

Cases: x

Deaths: y

Recovered: z

But as im using whatsapp, /n doesn't work and would send each individual line.  I've also tried ActionChains but that didn't work either.  Any idea on how I can get a key combination for Shift + Enter? Thanks.

Comment: I have seen a reference to `ActionsChain` and other solutions not working due to a bug in Chrome. Is that you're browser?

Comment: I believe you can use .send_keys(Key.SHIFT, Key.ENTER)

Answer (score 3):

For Python:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).key_down(Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

However, I could only get the above to work for Edge, not for Firefox nor Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you needed. Corresponding Java Implementation...

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
// Press SHIFT + ENTER            
actions.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT)
        .sendKeys(Keys.RETURN)
        .build()
        .perform();
```

Comment: And where did you import `Actions` from? `sendKeys` is *not* a Python method. Let me guess: You're a Java programmer.

Comment: Oh ! sorry forget to mention, it's java implementation though. Thanks @Booboo

Comment: I'd say this is still an acceptable answer since selenium with python and java are practically the same

Answer (score 2):

BooBoo's answer is close but you still need to release the shift and enter key, or your input text might get very weird.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).key_down(Keys.ENTER).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).key_up(Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61211459/12346562)