# How to Handle soft keys like search , enter etc in Appium android

Tags: android, testing, automation, appium

I am using Appium (java) to automate my android app.
I am struck in a scenario where I need to enter text and press search / enter key from Soft keyboard.
I tried many solutions , but none of them worked.
Has anyone tried this?
TRIED SO FAR:

```
WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.id("myId"));
        input.sendKeys(value); // the value we want to set to input
        input.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
         genericMethods.wait(1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
public void tapEnterButtonOnKeyboard() {
        ((AndroidDriver) driver).pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.ENTER);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it didn't worked. Even tried this -AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_SEARCH

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

selenium.keyPress("css=input.tagit-input.ui-autocomplete-input", "13");

Or

selenium.keyPressNative("10"); // Enter

References:

[Typing Enter/Return key in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629053/typing-enter-return-key-in-selenium)

[Press Enter key in Selenium script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799875/press-enter-key-in-selenium-script)

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html

Comment: I have a AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver as object, will it work?

Answer (score 1):

I am using the 1.11.0 Appium version and I tried this and it worked. Try this:

```
driver.executeScript("mobile:performEditorAction", ImmutableMap.of("action", "Search"));
```

**Note:**

> The "driver" is an AppiumDriver type.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably find that enter soft key object and execute tap event on it..It'll be under uiakeyboard node..

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This solution in JavaScript using wd worked for me:

`return driver.waitForElementById(<elementId>).type(<text to type>).click().execute( "mobile: performEditorAction", { "action": "search" } );`

This allowed me to find a text field, input some text, and submit a search command (same as clicking the search icon in the keyboard). Of course, you have to replace `<elementId>` and `<text to type>` with the proper values. See http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/mobile-command/ for details on "mobile: performEditorAction".