# Selenium webdrive page not loaded - tried to find invisible element and Wait

Tags: firefox, webdriver

Hi I am just learning Webdriver. The flow that I am automating has 5 screens. 2 of the screens, I was able to navigate using webdriver. After details are input in the 2nd screen and ENTER is clicked, the 3rd screen is not getting loaded in the Webdriver browser.

When I try this manually this works fine. I have tried out various logic for waiting for the page to laod and searching for invisible elements.

is this some limitation of the webdriver browser?

```
   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();


   driver.get("url");         
  // Find the text input element by its name         
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("clicButton"));
   // Enter something to search for 
  element.click();
  System.out.println("completed start");
  WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.name("contactphone"));
  element1.sendKeys("number");          
  // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element   
  //element1 = driver.findElement(By.id("the id"));
  //element1.click();
  element1.sendKeys(org.openqa.selenium.Keys.ENTER); 
  System.out.println("clicked continue");
  //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
  //WebElement element2 = wait.until(driver.findElement(By.name("name")));

  //wait.until(driver.findElement(By.name("name")).isDisplayed());

  new WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
       .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated (By.name("name")));
```

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 60 seconds waiting for presence of element located by: By.name: name 
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.6.0_20'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:255)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:270)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:222)
    at LoadUsers.main(LoadUsers.java:49)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

few options:

1. try to use Keys.Return instead of Keys.Enter
2. try to do element1.SendKeys(Keys.Return) on the input element and not on the submit button.
3. check this out: [typing-enter-return-key-in-selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629053/typing-enter-return-key-in-selenium)