# How to press 'Enter' once text is entered in the search field using Selenium WebDriver and java code in eclipse

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to write test case using WebDriver, TestNG in Eclipse.
Version of WebDriver is 2.39

In the test case I am trying to open a browser, enter site address, once it is loaded, find search field, enter text using Datadriven type from an excel sheet.

Once the first data is entered, I would like to click Return key on keyboard and wait till loads and clear it and enter next test from spreadsheet.

I am successfull in entering text,clearing, but not sure how to write code to press 'Return key' or Enter, please advise.

Apologies, I could not find this in search.

regards,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Typing Enter/Return key in Selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629053/typing-enter-return-key-in-selenium)

Answer (score 10):

You can simulate hit Enter key by adding "\n" to the entered text. For example `textField.sendKeys("text you type into field" + "\n")`.

upd: BTW, it has been already asked here [Typing Enter/Return key in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629053/typing-enter-return-key-in-selenium)

Comment: Sending \n appears not to be foolproof , while Keys.Enter does seem to do the job in such cases.

Comment: It depends on webdriver version, ja framework, implementation of particular text element. So, this is one of many possible options

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
driver.findElement(By.id("IDValue")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Answer (score 4):

Using this snippet you can skip using Enter key

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
element.sendKeys("your text");
element.submit();
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what I use as an example to enter multiple values into a field:
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//INPUT[@class='attr-new ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope placeholder'])[2]")).sendKeys("Linoleum" + Keys.ENTER + "Metal" + Keys.ENTER + "Electrical" + Keys.ENTER + "Lumber" + Keys.ENTER + "Fiberglass" + Keys.ENTER + "Masonry" + Keys.ENTER + "Paint" + Keys.ENTER + "Millwork" + Keys.ENTER + "Wood" + Keys.ENTER + "Pick Ups" + Keys.ENTER);`.

Answer (score -1):

I have already met a similar problem. The click() even is working from Selenium IDE but not from jUnit test. The solution was the using of submit() even that works. (But only in jUnit ;) ) Let's try it!

Comment: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.search > #Form_getSearchForm > fieldset > #Terms > div.middleColumn > #Form_getSearchForm_Terms")).sendKeys(s.getCell(0,i).getContents() "\n");                                                              got syntax error on token "\n"

Comment: Hm, By.cssSelector() is not the best, I think. It uses a little bit complex target...