# How can I simulate 'Control key' in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, key, enter

How can I simulate the enter key in Selenium webdriver?
I want to choose a menu in the drop down for countries and list is chosen only upon hitting enter or clicking one of the list options.
Here is my code uptill the point of the enter key. the code breaks at the 7th line.

```
it('Should let valid users login' .function () {
    browser.url('/customer/signup');    browser.element('#customer_user_attributes_first_name').setValue('Name');
    browser.element('#customer_user_attributes_last_name').setValue('lastname');
    browser.element('#customer_user_attributes_email').setValue('test@email.com');
    browser.element('#customer_company').setValue('company');
    browser.element('#customer_phone_number').setValue('2222222222');
    browser.click('.select2-selection__arrow')[0]
    browser.element('.select2-search__field').setValue('United States');
```

Comment: Refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629053/typing-enter-return-key-in-selenium

Comment: @Akbar This is for JS. if I add .sendKeys(Keys.ENTER) then I get an error that keys is not defined. Do you know of an import for keys ? error "1) Should let valid users login: Keys is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(browser.Key.ENTER).perform();
```

Comment: This did not work for me. SendKeys is undefined. We have an issue with Select2 I think