# How to press Down Arrow key followed by "Enter" button in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Java. I need to enter value into text box and press down arrow to select suggestions and then press Enter key.

So, my question is how to press Down Arrow key followed by "Enter" key?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629053/typing-enter-return-key-in-selenium

Comment: Can you post any code you have tried?

Answer (score 42):

You can import `Keys` and use these.

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys

WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);
WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

**Edit**

You could probably use one `sendKeys()` call:

```java
WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN, Keys.RETURN);
```

Comment: For me just worked with Keys.ARROW_DOWN and not Keys.DOWN

Comment: @EduardoLima are right, as writed on official doc in examples : https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/keyboard/#copy-and-paste

Answer (score 2):

For Ruby, this would be:

```
input_element = @driver.find_element(:id,'input_id')
input_element.send_keys(:arrow_down)
```

A list of special character keys can be found [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/0.0.28/Selenium/WebDriver/Keys)

Answer (score 0):

```
using Keys = OpenQA.Selenium.Keys;

//moves down arrow key from keyboard to the list of dropdown
IWebElement.SendKeys(Keys.Down);
//Hits Enter on the selected list from the dropdown
IWebElement.SendKeys(Keys.Return);
```

This will work.

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findelement(By.(locator(locator details)).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW-DOWN,Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and it worked for me.

```
WebElement dp_down = driver.findElement(By.xpath("enter-your-element-xpath-here");
dp_down.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN, Keys.RETURN);
```

This is working fine for me without any issues.
CHEERS!!!

Answer (score -1):

Even you can concatenate both the Down and Enter in a single statement.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys
WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN + Keys.ENTER);
```

Comment: OP asked for sequential, not pressing at the same time