# What is the best practice to simulate an ENTER or RETURN using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, enter, ui-testing

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629053/typing-enter-return-key-in-selenium) solution to my initial problem, which was to simulate an ENTER or RETURN key press using Selenium WebDriver.

However, in my code, I strictly want to use only one of the two `WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);` vs `WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);`.

What is the best practice when doing the same, since there seems to be divided opinion about using enter or return, since both work MOST of the time? In what scenarios would one or the other not work, and is there one which would ALWAYS work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a performancewise I do not get any change on both of these,

But yes I know one difference on them

`Keys.Enter` is used to enter key on the number pad

while

`Keys.Return` is used to one next to the letters

Generally I have preferred  `Keys.Enter`as sometimes in some browser `Keys.Return` is not worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Let us analyze **`Keys.ENTER`** and **`Keys.RETURN`** in details.

**`Keys.ENTER`** and **`Keys.RETURN`** both are from **`org.openqa.selenium.Keys`**, which extends **`java.lang.Enum<Keys>`** and implements **`java.lang.CharSequence`**

### Enum Keys :

**`Enum Keys`** is the representations of pressable keys that aren't text. These are stored in the Unicode PUA ([**`Private Use Area`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas)) code points, 0xE000-0xF8FF.

### Key Codes :

The special **`keys codes`** for them are as follows :

- **RETURN** = **`u'\ue006'`**
- **ENTER** = **`u'\ue007'`**

The implementation of all the **`Enum Keys`** are handled the same way.

Hence there is **No** **`Functional`** or **`Operational`** difference while working with either **`sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);`** or **`WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);`** through **Selenium**.

---

### Enter Key and Return Key :

On computer keyboards, the <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or the <kbd>Return</kbd> on Mac OSX) in most cases causes a command line, window form, or dialog box to operate its default function. This is typically to finish an "entry" and begin the desired process, and is usually an alternative to pressing an OK button.

The <kbd>Return</kbd> is often also referred as the <kbd>Enter</kbd> and they usually perform identical functions; however in some particular applications (mainly page layout) <kbd>Return</kbd> operates specifically like the **Carriage Return** key from which it originates. In contrast, the <kbd>Enter</kbd> is commonly labelled with its name in plain text on generic PC keyboards.

> **Wiki References** : [**`Enter Key`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enter_key) [**`Carriage Return`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return)

Answer (score 0):

As yourself, I failed to find a good explanation to this question online so I tested it myself using [this](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/d4e/raw-file/tip/key-event-test.html) Keyboard Events tester.

```
driver.get("https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/d4e/raw-file/tip/key-event-test.html");
WebElement textArea = driver.findElement(By.id("input"));

textArea.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
textArea.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

As a result I've got this output (this is `Keys.ENTER` followed by `Keys.RETURN`):
[image: Keyboard Events logger output]

So it seems like there is no difference between these two options.