# press enter key from phone keyboard in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, appium

```
String str1 = sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
String str2 = sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();

driver2.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@text='Start - press enter to drop marker']")).clear();
driver2.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@text='Start - press enter to drop marker']")).sendKeys(str1);
driver2.sendKeyEvent(AndroidKeyCode.ENTER);


driver2.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@text='End - press enter to drop marker']")).clear();
driver2.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@text='End - press enter to drop marker']")).sendKeys(str2);

driver2.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[@index='1']")).click();
```

I want to press enter key from phone keyboard in selenium, I used a method called sendKeyEvent but it is not working, can anyone suggest me how to press enter key from phone keyboard in selenium.

Comment: By _enter key from phone keyboard_ do you mean <key>Return</key>

Comment: yes in selenium

Answer (score 5):

As per your comment :

- To press <kbd>Enter</kbd> you can use :

  ```
  WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
  ```
- To press <kbd>Return</kbd> you can use :

  ```
  WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
  ```
- As you wanted to press it on the *phone keyboard* you can use :

  ```
  WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.KEYCODE_NUMPAD_ENTER);
  ```

Here are the helpful JavaDoc links :

- [*AndroidKeyCode Interface*](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/android/AndroidKeyCode.html)
- [ENTER](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/android/AndroidKeyCode.html#ENTER)
- [KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/android/AndroidKeyCode.html#KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER)
- [KEYCODE_ENTER](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/android/AndroidKeyCode.html#KEYCODE_ENTER)
- [KEYCODE_NUMPAD_ENTER](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/android/AndroidKeyCode.html#KEYCODE_NUMPAD_ENTER)
- Here you can find a [detailed discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823763/what-is-the-best-practice-to-simulate-an-enter-or-return-using-selenium-webdrive/47829873#47829873) on the following.

Comment: but i wanted to press it on the phone keyboard

Answer (score 1):

You can try any of the below code:

```
ApplicationSetup.driver.getKeyboard().pressKey(Keys.ENTER);
ApplicationSetup.driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
ApplicationSetup.driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have been using.

```
driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.ENTER);
```