# Selenium chrome Keys.ENTER not working on 'title-input'

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am having a problem sending the ENTER key using selenium. I've tried a variety of ways but it seems none of them are working.

**Element code :**

```
<span _ngcontent -c10>elementName</span>
```

After choosing the element, the element is changed to

```
 <input _ngcontent -c10 class="title-input" type="text">
```

-I have made sure I have the right element.

-Whenever there's a "RETURN" I also tried using "ENTER".

**Things I tried:**

--1--

```
textBox.click();
textBox.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

--2--

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.click(textBox);
actions.sendKeys(textBox, Keys.RETURN);
```

--3--

```
driver.getKeyBoard().pressKey(Keys.RETURN);
Thread.sleep(100);
driver.getKeyBoard().releaseKey(Keys.RETURN);
```

--4--

```
Robot r = new Robot();
textBox.click();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
Thread.sleep(100);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

A bit more of outerHTML as DebanjanB requested :

```
<div _ngcontent-c6 class="tab clicked" style="width: 50%;">
  <tab-header _ngcontent-c6 _nghost-c10>
    <span _ngcontent-c10 class="tab-header-name">
      <!---->
      <input _ngcontent-c10 class="title-input" type="text"> == $0
      <!---->
    </span>
    <!---->
    <span _ngcontent -c10 id="delete-tab" class="can-delete">x</span>
    <!---->
    <!---->
    <img _ngcontent-c10 id="not-pin-tab" src="assets/images/notPin.png">
  <tab-header>
</div>
```

Comment: Once the element is changes to `<input _ngcontent -c10 class="title-input" type="text">` why do you want to send only `Keys.RETURN` when it is `type="text"` ?

Comment: To save my input, as I changed it

Comment: Which input? Did you remove some steps in-between? I think `_ngcontent` and `-c10` will take care to save your input. You just need to [`focusout`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onfocusout)

Comment: I'm afraid it does not.. Any other ideas? At the moment the only way to save it is by clicking Enter.. As I only develop the automation I've posted what I found using F12

Comment: Can you update the question with a bit more of the _outerHTML_ to confirm if the element is within a form ?

Comment: @DebanjanB I've added a bit more for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned that **Keys.RETURN** didn't work here are a few alternatives :

- As the *WebElement* is a *Angular Element* you have to induce [*WebDriverWait*](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-) for the [*element to be clickable*](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) as follows :

  ```
  WebElement my_element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(textBox));
  ```
- Next you can attempt for the `click()` and sending `Keys.RETURN` as follows :

  ```
  my_element.click()
  my_element.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
  ```
- You can also try for `Keys.Enter` as an alternative as follows :

  ```
  my_element.click()
  my_element.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
  ```

  You can find a detailed discussion in [*What is the best practice to simulate an ENTER or RETURN using Selenium WebDriver*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823763/what-is-the-best-practice-to-simulate-an-enter-or-return-using-selenium-webdrive/47829873#47829873)
- Incase the *WebElement* is with in a `<form>` tag you can also try to invoke `submit()` as follows :

  ```
  my_element.click()
  my_element.submit();
  ```

Comment: It seems like I do not have ExpectedConditions class, do you have any other suggestions? I do have "ExpectedCondition <T>" under the same path. Thanks!

Comment: Add the import, that should be simple.

Comment: I'm working on a seperated network and importing the class will be a long way which can take up to 72 hours which is why I've asked if you got any other suggestions :)

Comment: Thanks this was driving me crazy for hours. Had the same problem as op. This solution worked the best!