# Can I Just Do \n Instead of Key.ENTER?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Working with `selenium-webdriver`, I see this type code: `await inputField.sendKeys("BrowserStack", Key.ENTER);`

Seems that just doing: `await inputField.sendKeys("BrowserStack\n");` works just as well (replace `Key.ENTER` with `\n`). Is that , or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Escape Sequences for Character and String Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6):

```
\ n    /* \u000a: linefeed LF */
```

Essentially, `\n` is the escape character for strings that is replaced with the new line object. Writing `\n` in a string will print out a new line instead of the `\n`.

Using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) similar behaviour can be simulated using either:

- *`Key.ENTER`*
- *`Key.RETURN`*

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [What is the best practice to simulate an ENTER or RETURN using Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47829873/7429447)

Comment:  Well, it seems to run the test just fine either way. I was guessing that maybe for maximum compatibility with older browsers we might need to spell out `Key.RETURN` instead of just `\n`. But `\n` does trigger, for instance, a submission in browser.

Comment: yeap, that's correct, it should behave fine either way.