# how to press enter in selenium python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, submit, instagram, enter

I want to search a special keyword in Instagram. For example, I want to search this word:"fast food". I can send this key in search box. But, when I use submit method in Selenium by Python3, it doesn't work and give me error. This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url="https://www.instagram.com/p/pTPI-kyX7g/?tagged=resurant"
driver.get(url)

#login_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/span/section/main/article/div[2]/div[2]/p/a""")
#login_button.click()
import time
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
search_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/span/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/input""")
search_button.send_keys("fast food")
search_button.submit()
```

This is gave error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: ./ancestor-or-self::form
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Can you supply the relevant piece of HTML?

Comment: <input class="_avvq0 _o716c" placeholder="Search" value="" type="text">

Comment: On what code line the exception is given. I don't see a code line with the locator mentioned in the exception.

Comment: <input class="_avvq0 _o716c" placeholder="Search" value="" type="text"><span class="_i13c9 coreSpriteSearchIcon"></span><div class="_gftfm"></div><div class="_c7jlt coreSpriteSearchClear"></div>

Comment: It is more completed than previous code. Are you need to xpath?

Comment: All of thins are correct. "Send keys" is worked well, but, only enter is not pressed.

Comment: I mean in your python code, on what line the exception occurs. Can you add the full stacktrace to your question.

Comment: This error is happened in this part of code in python:
search_button.submit()

Comment: It doesn't work. Only the error was removed and the search press didn't pressed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of. submit() try '.send_keys(u'\ue007')'

See: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.keys

Comment: It doesn't work. Only the error was removed and the search press didn't pressed

Comment: Your solution is similar to one of my ways:
search_button.send_keys("fast",Keys.RETURN)

Comment: It''s good practice to share in your question all that you already tried to solve the problem.

Comment: Here a lot of information is found about problems with SendKeys for different languages: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629053/typing-enter-return-key-in-selenium

Comment: I can solve it and I share my response in answer box

Answer (score 1):

It need more clicks:

```
search_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/span/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/input""")

    search_button.send_keys("fast")
    while True:
        search_button.send_keys(u'\ue007')
```

Answer (score 0):

That is very interesting. Another solution is better. It is very important to know that, you must press 2 Enter press on Instagram search box. So, for eliminating while loop, you can use this code:
search_button.send_keys("#fast")

```
time.sleep(5)
search_button.send_keys(u'\ue007')
search_button.send_keys(u'\ue007')
```