# how to press enter in selenium python with out any error?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler, enter

I want to search a special keyword in Instagram. For example, I want to search this word:"internet". I can send this key in search box. But, when I use submit method in Selenium by Python3, it doesn't work and give me error. This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url="https://www.instagram.com/p/pTPI-kyX7g/?tagged=resurant"
driver.get(url)

#login_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/span/section/main/article/div[2]/div[2]/p/a""")
#login_button.click()
import time
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
search_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/span/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/input""")
search_button.send_keys("internet",Keys.RETURN)
```

This is no anu error, but it dosen't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to press enter in selenium python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49178236/how-to-press-enter-in-selenium-python)

Comment: There are different. In contrary to your sent link, my code has no any error, but, it doesn't work

Comment: Are you looking to browse the first result of a search in detail? This is exact behavior if you do this for yourself in instagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By this code enter will be pressed, but, after pressing and loading page an error will be occurred:

```
search_button.send_keys("internet")
    while True:
        search_button.send_keys(u'\ue007')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
 searchbox     driver.find_element_by_xpath( Xpath/locator for search box).sendKey("internet")    
 search button driver.find_element_by_xpath(Xpath/locator for the search key button).click
```

which is you  send the  "internet" to that edit Box first then looking for that search button and perform `.click`
not input the search text and send the key at sametime

Comment: can you post a sample source code of that part of application

Answer (score 0):

Use this solution please:

```
time.sleep(5)
search_button.send_keys(u'\ue007')
search_button.send_keys(u'\ue007')
```