# Python Selenium Return Key

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I was looking at the documentation located here: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html

In the documentation, they are importing the library like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common import Keys
```

When I use Keys (with a capital "K"), it doesn't work (unlike what they are doing in the documentation), I get the following error message:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Keys' from 'selenium.webdriver.common
```

When I use this, it works:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common import keys
```

But then when I use this code:

```
WebElement_pw.send_keys(keys.Return)
```

I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.common.keys' has no attribute 'RETURN'
```

Using Python, how can I use the Enter key with Selenium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

See reference here: [Typing the Enter/Return key in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629053/typing-the-enter-return-key-in-selenium)
(and it's also mentioned in the documentation that you shared)