# selenium: Handle "Allow this site to open the XXX link with YYY"

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

How do I handle this popup with python/selenium? (Chrome and Firefox answers appreciated.)

A. How do I cancel it?

B. How would I do the open link?

C. Are there any Chrome Options/Firefox Profiles to ignore this popup?

[image]

Comment: I think you can pass it using enter key. check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629053/typing-the-enter-return-key-in-selenium) to automate enter key

Comment: Your question is missing a focus. Each question here should be about single issue while you asking here 3 questions